# Rails multiple roles defined in relationship with a third party

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, inheritance, single-table-inheritance

I am building a small app which has classes User, Student, Tutor, Meeting.

Each user can be tutor in one Meeting, but student in another meeting. I have been thinking about how to model these relationship.

Right now, I have a User model, a separate Participant model with an attribute Role = "tutor"/"student". Tutor and Student extend Participant using single-table inheritance, and belong to Meeting.

However, I wonder if this is a good design. (It seems to be unintuitive to me).

What would you do in my situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is acceptable but there are other ways that are cleaner. You could design you `Meeting` model like this:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :as => :studens
belongs_to :tutor, :foreign_key => 'tutor_id', :class_name => 'User'
```

Your `User` Model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :meetings, :as => :meetings_taken
has_many :meetings_given, :foreign_key => 'tutor_id', :class_name => 'Meeting'
```

So you would only need two models.

// edit

For propose, accept, decline,.. I would create a `Invitation` Model `user_id:integer` (Invited User), `meeting_id`(Through this you know who is allowed to invite other people because Meeting belongs to the tutor), `status:string` (waiting, accepted, delicesed might be options) maybe `explaination:text` (When somebody delices).

Comment: Your solution is very natural and intuitive. However, tutor and student have different actions (propose, accept, decline etc.) vis-a-vis each meeting. That is, per event, I must store such action somewhere. How would you implement this?

Comment: Thanks David. This is similar to what I have. Since Invitation have two distinct roles, I create two classes inheriting Invitation (or in my case, Participant). I wonder if I should make Invitation inherits User directly though.